# Загрузка фото на стену ВКонтакте

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, curl, вконтакте

При попытке загрузить фото я получаю следующий ответ:

```
string(72) "{"server":627930,"photo":"[]","hash":"a8b63b2ee64837229d28e2066f066253"}"
```

Почему в photo ничего нет? В чём ошибка?

```
        $PhotoUpload_data=array(
            'group_id'=>$group_id,
            'access_token'=>$access_token,
        );

        $response=json_decode(file_get_contents($api.'photos.getWallUploadServer?'.http_build_query($PhotoUpload_data)));

        $imag='@src/1.jpg';
        $photo_array=array('photo'=>$imag);


        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => $response->response->upload_url,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($photo_array),
        ));
        $json = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);


        var_dump($json);
```

Comment: А что такое `@src/1.jpg`? Вы ж передаёте какую-то строку вместо  содержимого файла с картинкой.

Comment: @klopp

$imag = base64_encode(fread(fopen('src/1.jpg', "r"), filesize('src/1.jpg')));
$imag = file_get_contents('src/1.jpg');

тоже не работает.

Comment: В любом случае вам нужно передавать не имя файла, а его содержимое. Дальше - разбирайтесь как правильно формировать данные для POST. Явно не `http_build_query`.

Answer (score 1):

Замените относительный путь к файлу на абсолютный через `realpath`

И `http_build_query` тут не нужно.

Так должно сработать:

```
    $imag=realpath('src/1.jpg');
    $photo_array=array('photo'=>'@'.$imag);


    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $response->response->upload_url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $photo_array,
    ));
    $json = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```